# CakePHP Admin Panel and Front End

Tags: cakephp

I am new to CakePHP. These days, I create an application some like hotscripts. I need an admin panel for site manager to add new articles/apps and front end for public visitors.

I am looking for a solution for this. I have alread made the router_prefix to admin. For example, in the CategoriesController.

```
public function admin_add() {

}

public function view($id) {
}
```

As I know, this is one of the solution. In the CategoriesController, I set

```
$this->Auth->allow('view');
```

so that visitors can visit this page without login. My question is, is this really a solution for admin and front product?

Thanks in advance!

```
        public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => 'controller',
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'admin' => true,
                'controller' => 'dashboards',
                'action' => 'index',
            ),
            'loginError' => 'Invalid account specified',
            'authError' => 'No Permission',

        ),
```

Thank you Anh Pham!!! I followed your suggestion and add this code to AppController. I now have no idea what is admin param means in loginRedirect? Could you explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
is this really a solution for admin and front product?
```

Yes, you will have to put `$this->Auth->allow('view');` in beforeFilter, and remember to call the app controller beforeFilter also (most likely you set the Auth setting there). So it'll look like this:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('view');
}
```

Edit: the 'admin' there is the prefix: it means after the login, it will redirect to yoursite.com/admin/dashboards. If you don't set admin=>true, it will redirect to yoursite.com/dashboards. It's just a common practice to use prefix for group-based access control. (Later on, if you have more than 1 group of logged-in user: admin, sub-admin, and so on, you'll need to set Auth to restrict the access level; but it's pretty simple).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into [Croogo](http://croogo.org). It's a CMS built on CakePHP.

Comment: Thank you. I have downloaded it. Awesome!